# DrawerNavigator redirects to first route at opening

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

// AppContainer.js

```
const AuthNavigator = createStackNavigator(...code);

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    MyAccount: MyAccountScreen,
    Home: HomeScreen,
  }
);

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    MyAccount: MyAccountScreen,
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthNavigator,
      AppNavigator,
      DrawerNavigator,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: AuthNavigator,
    }
  )
);
```

// HomeScreen.js I call:

```
onPress={() =>
  this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())
}
```

It opens the modal, but always goes automatically to MyAccountScreen without touch anything. The expected behaviour it's only open the modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, which is actually correct. But you have some flows in understanding how a `DrawerNavigator` should work. You cannot open the drawer if you're not on the Drawer.

I see that you have `HomeScreen` defined in 2 Navigators. And I have a feeling that you want to be able to navigate from `Home` to/from `MyAccount` using the `DrawerNavigator`, which means that both those routes have to be inside the `DrawerNavigator` and you want the HomeScreen to be the first screen that is visible by default.

```
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    MyAccount: MyAccountScreen,
  }
);
```

Which you kind of already have. The misconception that you have is that for your current routes, you don't need the `AppNavigator`, you could simply rename the above one as `AppNavigator` and your navigation configuration should look something like this:

```
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    MyAccount: MyAccountScreen,

  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthNavigator,
      AppNavigator,
      DrawerNavigator,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: AuthNavigator,
    }
  )
);
```

And that's it. Now when you navigate to `AppNavigator`, the first displayed route will be `Home` and opening the Drawer will just display the Drawer and won't automatically navigate you to `MyAccountScreen`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've spent like 2 hours trying to figure out why this was happening!

Comment: Glad I could help.